# Python newbie - PIP / invalid syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-dateutil

Ok, totally newbie to programming and python. Running Windows 7, python 2.7 x64.
I am trying in install `dateutil` package using `pip`.

I installed `pip`, `numpy` and `pandas`... which were pretty straightforward as they are `exe` files.

I am now trying to use `pip` to install `dateutil`. In the Python Shell, I have typed:

```
pip install dateutil
```

and

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

I continue to get `"Invalid Syntax"` errors at the install command. What am I doing wrong here?  I have also tried this in the python command line.

I have checked my modules installed and I have both `pip` and `easy_install`.  Really confused right now...I also have tried running the setup script for `dateutil` and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\python-dateutil-1.5.tar\python-dateutil-1.5\setup.py", line 14, in <module>
    TOPDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__) or "."
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Help please! Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: try using command prompt instead of the python shell :)

Comment: I have also used the python command prompt C:\Python27\python.exe and I get a similar error.  File "<stdin>", line 1 pip SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You don't need to start the python interpreter. Just launch the `cmd` and type `pip install dateutil`.

Answer (score 15):

You don't type that in the Python shell. You type it in the command prompt (haven't used Windows for years, but it used to be called `cmd`).

Comment: ahhh.  the windows command prompt.  got it and success.  thanks for the quick reply!!

Comment: @user2338676: if this answer solved your problem, you should mark this answer as accepted with clicking the green tick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
easy_install
```

by download [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) easy way to download any Python packages